# Attaching a circuit on to a PCB

Tags: pcb-design

Currently I have a circuit on my breadboard but the problem is I have no idea how to paste this circuit on the zero PCB board. basically the circuit I created was using LDR, transistor, LED and a resistor to make sure the LED turns on only if the light was off. This was a sample circuit I designed on a breadboard:

[image]

However I have a problem, I do not know or have any knowledge on pasting a a series circuit on a zero PCB. I would appreciate how I can make this circuit on this bread board work on a Zero PCB. I know how to solder it on, but I just do not understand how I can align the components properly and the videos on youtube seem too difficult for me as a non engineer student.

Comment: Fritzing might be a good resource to start with: https://fritzing.org/learning/get-started/ -- although one of the main criticisms of Fritzing is that it tends to skip professional-grade schematics in favor of wiring diagrams, it's probably a bit friendlier to the novice/hobbyist.

Comment: What is a "zero pcb"?

Comment: @AnalogKid It's basically Veroboard: https://www.robomart.com/general-purpose-zero-pcb

Comment: You can get proto-pcb that [acts exactly like a breadboard](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/BusBoard-Prototype-Systems/ST1?qs=NGErKr1RxMAXV5lcv8OdyQ%3D%3D&gclid=Cj0KCQjws7TqBRDgARIsAAHLHP5YdID3wciyjG3mSJRuBtRg8iM9xRRx7hRgYxzTTI3fOHGYvaBVg4EaAuONEALw_wcB)

Comment: DS8 - thanks.  I have lots of that, but it, like me, is older than that term.

Answer (score 2):

First, draw out a schematic for your circuit based on how you already have it connected. This shows *what* is connected, but it is not important how the components are placed on the breadboard; distances don't matter on a schematic. A good schematic will make it easier to understand and explain what your circuit is doing, and it will help you make the right connections on your board.

It looks like a Zero PCB is a board with holes for you to put components through and solder them. They will not be connected to any other components unless you make the connection yourself. You can place them really however you like, but certain placements will make for more convenient connections later.

You need to solder your own wires between the different holes on the bottom side of the board, or use any extra length from the leads already on the components. To solder another wire to connect two components, you can choose if you want to use bare wire (remove the insulation entirely) or keep the insulation on except for the ends. For very short connections, it's easier to just use a length of bare wire, but it's better to have insulation on longer connections so you don't have any accidental shorts to other components.

Lay out the wire between the two components you want to connect, cut it to the right length, and solder the two ends on top of the pads where the components are soldered. (You said you already know how to solder, so I won't go into detail there unless you would like more.)